# Why would you want to use a MVC 3 Template?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

A few weeks ago, I figured out how to write my own DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates. I do find them useful as I can write something as this: `@Html.DisplayForModel("my_awesome_template")` which will display whatever is in the "my_awesome_template" and use the current Model in the View. Fantastic right?

Well, I have written my views in so many different ways, that now I am ending right back to way I first wrote them: Just straight in the View with no partials or templates, and using ViewModels. Why? Because I lack ultimate flexibility and lose consistency. For example: If I had in my DisplayTemplate, `@Model.HamSandwhichText`, since this is in my template, I can only move it around inside my template and not in the actual View. Technically I could use it directly in the View, but at that point I just broke consistency. This means that the View and the Template both have access to the same thing. I don't like this. I'm assuming since I am using ViewModels I will not have to worry so much about templates.

But, what is the real reason to use a template? I do notice it makes displaying lists a little bit cleaner and easier; but I still don't like it.

Comment: abstraction - that is, templates are a means to abstract.

Comment: This is what someone else told me as well and showed me a good use case for it. But it still allows the View and Template to access the same thing; which is what he was worried about as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons to use editor/display templates:

1) Syntax sugar. It helps make your html easier to read by isolating specific chunks of code. 
Most of my views/layouts are very lightweight due to my usage of:

- partial views
- templates
- sections

2) It makes code more maintainable. Separating your html into concise chunks of code with a purpose can really help you focus on what you're working on.  I can easily add/remove/replace entire sections of code with ease.

Comment: This is why I used them in the first place. Now, I think it does make it more maintainable, to a certain extent. If everything used templates I would be searching for files and sifting through DisplayTemplate and EditorTemplate folders to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Searching through folder structure is always easier than trying to read 100's-1000's of lines of html.

Comment: I agree absolutely. It depends on how complex your page is. At this point, Partial Views would be more useful than Templates in this case.

Comment: Templates really shine when you have a set of model classes that inherit from lets say a common base class. If you wanted to list a bunch of animal types that all derive from animal. You could use a template w/ tabular data to display the common properties of all the animals in your data. Your model would be type 'Animal' for the template and then you could pass it anything that inherits from that.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. In my program I don't have any base classes for my Models. That could be a reason why I am smelling something funny with the templates. I'll try to see what I can come up with. Thanks!

Comment: Interfaces work as well. (I prefer interfaces in most scenarios)